# Fatal error showing while configuring site in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to configure site into the Zend framework but while configuring the code it showing following error:

```
  1. Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ExpediaRate in 
      /var/www/sitename/application/models/Search.php on line 3012 Call
      Stack: 0.0003 371520 1.  {main}()
      /var/www/sitename/public/index.php:0 0.0087 1220360 
  2.
      Zend_Application->bootstrap() /var/www/sitename/public/index.php:97
      0.0087 1220404 
  3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
      /var/www/sitename/library/Zend/Application.php:355 0.0087 1220404 
  4.
      Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
      /var/www/sitename/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:583
      0.0191 2475264 
  5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
      /var/www/sitename/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:619
      0.0191 2475452 
  6. Bootstrap->_initModels() /var/www/sitename/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:666
      0.0290 3903156 7.
 require_once('/var/www/sitename/application/models/Search.php')
          /var/www/sitename/application/Bootstrap.php:32
```

Not able to understand what is problem here.

Comment: Can you write a little bit of your code?

Comment: Actually it is configuration related error because code is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have created the  class `ExpediaRate`  two times or else look at your `application.ini` file may be your `include path` is set twice .

Comment: yes you are correct problem was in application.ini. Thanks :-)